# restore tab state on switching from navigation drawer

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, tabs, navigation-drawer

I have 4 tabs in Fragment A.The first tab has a listview. I have attached a Navigation drawer switching between other 3 tabs, Fragment B, C and D. Now when I switch from Fragment A to Fragment B and back, the first tab doesn't show the listview. But when I switch from 3rd tab and come back to 1st tab it gets the listview data and loads it. What am I doing wrong? I have attached my MainActivity which has implemented navigation drawer and my HomeFragment which has four tabs.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements {


// index to identify current nav menu item
public static int navItemIndex = 0;

// tags used to attach the fragments

// toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
private String[] activityTitles;

// flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
private Handler mHandler;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDatabase1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mHandler = new Handler();

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    // Navigation view header

    // load toolbar titles from string resources
    activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

    // load nav menu header data
    loadNavHeader();

    // initializing navigation menu
    setUpNavigationView();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navItemIndex = 0;
        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
        loadHomeFragment();
    }
}

/***
 * Load navigation menu header information
 * like background image, profile image
 * name, website, notifications action view (dot)
 */
private void loadNavHeader() {

}

/***
 * Returns respected fragment that user
 * selected from navigation menu
 */
private void loadHomeFragment() {
    // selecting appropriate nav menu item
    selectNavMenu();

    // set toolbar title
    setToolbarTitle();

    // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
    // just close the navigation drawer
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        // show or hide the fab button
        toggleFab();
        return;
    }

    // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
    // when switching between navigation menus
    // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect
    // This effect can be seen in GMail app
    Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    };

    // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
    }

    // show or hide the fab button
    toggleFab();

    //Closing drawer on item click
    drawer.closeDrawers();

    // refresh toolbar menu
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;
        case 1:

        case 2:

        case 3:
        case 4:
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}

private void setToolbarTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
}

private void selectNavMenu() {
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
}

private void setUpNavigationView() {
    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    navItemIndex = 0;

                    break;
                case R.id.nav_live:
                    navItemIndex = 1;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_edit:
                    navItemIndex = 2;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_competitions:
                    navItemIndex = 3;
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    navItemIndex = 4;
                    break;

                case R.id.nav_about_us:
                    // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CompetitionActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_report_bug:
                    // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReportBugActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                default:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
            }

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            loadHomeFragment();

            return true;
        }
    });


    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }

    // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
    // when user is in other fragment than home
    if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
        // checking if user is on other navigation menu
        // rather than home
        if (navItemIndex != 0) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
            return;
        }
    }

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Exit")
            .setMessage("Are you sure?")
            .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("no", null).show();

    //System.exit(0);

    //super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    // show menu only when home fragment is selected
    if (navItemIndex == 0) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }

    // when fragment is notifications, load the menu created for notifications
    if (navItemIndex == 3) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notifications, menu);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        auth.signOut();
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// show or hide the fab
private void toggleFab() {
    if (navItemIndex == 0)
        fab.show();
    else
        fab.hide();
}



@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
private int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    float density = getApplication().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return Math.round((float)dp * density);
}

@Override
public void setActionBarTitle(String home) {

}`**
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


private AppCompatActivity aca=new AppCompatActivity();

//private class Act extends AppCompatActivity {

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;


//tabs
private String[] mPlanetTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_question_answer_black_24dp,
        R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp,
        R.drawable.ic_people_black_24dp,
        R.drawable.ic_face_black_24dp,
};


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private LayoutInflater inflator;
public ViewGroup container;
private Bundle savedInstancesState;

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

LayoutInflater inflater;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Context context=getContext();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    //viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();

    return v;
}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);

    ColorStateList colors;

    colors = getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.tab_icon);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        Drawable icon = tab.getIcon();

        if (icon != null) {
            icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(icon);
            DrawableCompat.setTintList(icon, colors);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView(){
    super.onDestroyView();
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter((getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag();
    adapter.addFrag();
    adapter.addFrag();
    adapter.addFrag();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        //return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        return null;
    }
}

public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    aca.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}


/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);

    void setActionBarTitle(String home);
}
```

}